# Session storage being cleared on selecting the url and press enter

Tags: url, session-cookies, pageload, session-storage

I am using a session storage value to verify the user to redirect to other page or not.
like ex :- if session storage doesn't exists go to verification url then if successful adding session storage value true goes to next page. page.url

The problem is when he is on page.url when i select the url and clicking it , the session storage which i created is not there and going back to  verification url and when i click back the session storage is there for this particular page but it is working fine when i do a normal reload and hard reload.

Can someone explain what is happening here